# Android layout with a MapView and other elements: unexpected results (I know... it's probably me...)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview

So, I have this layout file:

```
<merge>
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
          android:id="@+id/mapView"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent".../>
    <LinearLayout topNav
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top".../>
    <LinearLayout bottomNav 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom".../>
</merge>
```

The idea is to have a top and a bottom bars with buttons for doing stuff.

When I do this, the bars show correctly, with the map in the middle expanding the whole thing except for the bars. I then added

```
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

and a funny thing happens: the zoom controls appear OVER THE LOWER BAR, without touch focus (i.e. when I touch them, I actually click the buttons **below** in the bar itself).

I tried playing with android:weight to no avail (i.e. set the weight=1 for the map, set the weight=0.5 for the bars)

Suggestions?

Thanks!

--

llappall

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue may be with the lauout_height set to "fill_parent" insted of "wrap_content"  for the map view.

Can you try this:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
          android:id="@+id/mapView"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content".../>
```

Comment: Good thinking, but it didn't help. I still got the zoom in/out controls over the bottom nav. Thanks though! Any other ideas?